# Add values before Doctrine Flush

Tags: php, symfony, crud, flush

I would like to add values before flushing.
My others values are from a Form which is mapped with my Entity, so when i try to use **setData()**, my fields stay at "null".

Code :

```
    public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('BlogBlogBundle:Blog')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Blog entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $editForm->get('date')->setData(date("Y-m-d"));
        $usr= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $usr->getUsername();
        $editForm->get('author')->setData($usr);
        var_dump($editForm);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('blogAdmin_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return $this->render('BlogBlogBundle:Admin:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **dont** need to use **getData** or **setData** on the **form**,
you should use the setter of the entity itself. 
What you will save/persist is not the form, its the entity.
The form is also using the setters on the entity class for the data which was sent.

like:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('BlogBlogBundle:Blog')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Blog entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $usr = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        //don't know what you wanna do with the username
        $usr->getUsername();
        //use the setter for the date... maybe $entity->setCreatedAt()
        $entity->setDate(date("Y-m-d"));
        //also use the setter for the user on the entity
        $entity->setAuthor($usr);
        var_dump($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('blogAdmin_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return $this->render('BlogBlogBundle:Admin:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: It does not work, i got the same result (null for the date and the author)

Comment: sorry i still dumped the form, but you have to dump the entity... just edited now

Comment: I did the changes, but date and author are still 'null' (the setters are the good ones)

Comment: sorry, i cant find anything else... did you tried a var_dump($this->date); in setDate or a var_dump($this->author) in setAuthor? Normally when you set data on a class, afterwards the class should contain the data...

Comment: what does the log say?

Comment: DBALException: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Blog (date, title, author, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "dfgh", null, "<p>hdfhdfdfhhf<\/p>"]:

Comment: It works now, my bad, i forgot to update the createAction method ! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to change entity that you mapped to the form and use correct entity fields setters(I've tried to guess). Try to modify:

```
 ...
 if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $entity->setDate(date("Y-m-d"));
        $usr= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $usr->getUsername();
        $entity->setAuthor($usr);
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
        ...
    }
```

Comment: You forgot persist your entity